# Why is this forloop running if the if statement is false?

Tags: java

My for loop is still being executed even if my if statement is false. For example I type something random instead of straight line and the forloop will still run and output the cost. Why is that?

```
if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("applesauce"));
{
    for (i = 0; i <span; i++) 
    {
        total = total * apple;
        additional++;
        System.out.println(total);

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry sotirios, I didn't know the semicolon terminated the if statement. I didn't search for that beforehand because I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: No need to apologize. A duplicate isn't _bad_.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("applesauce"));  <--
```

You terminated your statement right away with an `;` When you write `;` at the end of statement it terminates right there.

Your current code can be translated as

```
if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("applesauce")) {

}

{
    for (i = 0; i <span; i++) 
    {
        total = total * apple;
        additional++;
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Been looking at it for awhile